# Alert shows lots of unnecessary information

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, alert

I use google script and I call `alert`. It runs, but alert shows lots of unnecessary information. How can I clear unnecessary information?

code:

```
alert("Update "+ name + " successfully!");
```

I want to delete the red mark:

[image: alert screenshot]

Comment: What unnecessary information does it show? What is `name`?

Comment: You can see my picture

Comment: That information is added by the browser and you cannot remove it. You may find that creating your own modal solves your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is browser specific text that cannot be altered. Try making a custom alert on your own if you really don't need this text.

For example - https://sweetalert2.github.io/

You can also Google to find more custom alerts and choose the right one for your project.

Comment: okey, Thanks you ! I will try it because i think can modify alert ^^